# How to install a dependency from a submodule in Python?

Tags: python, git-submodules, distutils

I have a Python project with the following structure (irrelevant source files omitted for simplicity):

```
myproject/
    mysubmodule/
        setup.py
    setup.py
```

The file `myproject/setup.py` uses `distutils.core.setup` to install the module `myproject` and the relevant sources. However, `myproject` requires `mysubmodule` to be installed (this is a git submodule). So what I am doing right now is:

```
myproject/$ cd mysubmodule
myproject/mysubmodule/$ python setup.py install
myproject/mysubmodule/$ cd ..
myproject/$ python setup.py install
```

This is too tedious for customers, especially if the project will be extended by further submodules in the future.

Is there a way to automate the installation of `mysubmodule` when calling `myproject/setup.py`?

Comment: Installing modules manually requires some skills, so, it can be too difficult for  _customers_

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why I want to minimize the effort.

Comment: are those *git* submodules, or did you just use the name "submodule" for a subdirectory with a python module?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember @chrisinmtown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a package for `mysubmodule` with its own `setup.py` and let the top-level package depend on that package in its `setup.py`. This means you only need to make the packages / dependencies available and run `python setup.py install` on the top-level package.

The question then becomes how to ship the dependencies / packages to your customers but this can be solved by putting them in a directory and configuring `setup.py` to include that directory when searching for dependencies.

The alternative is to "vendor" `mysubmodule` which simply means including it all in one package (no further questions asked) and having one `python setup.py install` to install the main package. For example, `pip` vendors (includes) `requests` so it can use it without having to depend on that `requests` package.

Comment: Could you provide more details about how to specify the dependency in the `setup.py` of the top-level package?

Comment: Saying specifically how you edit `setup.py` to specify that it should install the submodule as the dependency would answer the question.

Comment: In addition to this answer, with some more details, is available here:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365579/how-do-i-deal-with-projects-within-projects-in-python?newreg=7f2e49cd2c7c4efe9c57380e586d4aa0

Comment: Difficult to understand why this is the accepted answer .. the OP shows clearly that mysubmodule already has its own setup.py. What additional magic is required in the top-level setup.py?

Answer (score 6):

`setuptools.find_packages()` is able to discover submodules

Your `setup.py` should look like

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
# ...
)
```