# Setuptools - find_package and automatic submodule dependancies management

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, dependency-management

I'm trying to setup for myself a number of small-ish support libraries & project in python. I intent it to be modular and manage those as git submodule, to be imported into other git repos. That part works well.

What I can't manage well is the dependancies of those submodule within python. I'm trying to make setuptools.find_package() do that, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113862/how-to-install-a-dependency-from-a-submodule-in-python) somewhat has what I am looking for, but it is phrased at such at high level that I cannot seem to get the implementation right.

My objectives:

- I don't want to have to explicitely list the submodule's dependancies in the parent module's requirements.txt or setup.py. I have made it "work" this way. But ultimately on bigger projects that's not a viable path, so I want to do things right from the start.
- The structure should make sense for the submodules as standalone project, as well as when they are used within other project. I don't mind if the structure as to be different from what I have below. I just want to still be able to use the submodules on their own.

Here's what I have:

```
MyProj
├── MyProj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── submodule
│       ├── setup.py
│       └── submodule
│           ├── hello.py
│           └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

MyProj.setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

""" a minimalist setup.py sample structure """

setup(
   name='MyProj',
   version='0.1.0',
   author='An Awesome demo of the basics of using pkgs',
   author_email='blablabla.it@gmail.com',
   packages=find_packages(),
   description='An awesome package that does something',
   install_requires=["PyYAML"],
)
```

submodule.setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

""" a minimalist setup.py sample structure """

setup(
   name='submodule',
   version='0.1.0',
   author='An Awesome demo of the basics of using pkgs',
   author_email='blababla.it@gmail.com',
   packages=find_packages(),
   license='license.txt',
   description='An awesome package that does something',
   install_requires=["numpy"],
)
```

MyProj.main:

```
from MyProj.submodule.submodule.hello import count_matrix

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_matrix())
```

`hello.py` just builds a matrix using numpy (to check the submodule's dependancies are properly managed even when imported elsewhere), and then MyProj.main just calls `hello.py`.

If I run:

```
pip install .
```

from /MyProj, then MyProj installs fine along with its PyYaml dependency:

```
Successfully built MyProj
Installing collected packages: PyYAML, MyProj
  Attempting uninstall: MyProj
    Found existing installation: MyProj 0.1.0
    Uninstalling MyProj-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled MyProj-0.1.0
Successfully installed MyProj-0.1.0 PyYAML-5.3.1
```

However, if I run MyProj.main, then `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`, and I can see anyway from the previous pip install that numpy wasn't installed. Nor was submodule for that matter.